# Application.WorksheetFunction.Log doesn´t working

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone help me with decimal logarithm?
How it is possible that with one constant all is ok but another is not calculated (even with same formula)? Thanks a lot

```
    Dim SumaLpi(1 To 22) As Double 'suma(10^(0.1Lpi))
    Dim Lp_stredni(1 To 22) As Double
    Dim Lw(1 To 22) As Double
    Dim p(0 To 100) As Double
    Dim Lpi(0 To 100) As Double
    Dim Konst As Double

    Konst = 0.0000000004

    For i = 1 To 22
    SumaLpi(i) = 0
        For j = 1 To N
                p(j) = Cells(5 + j, i + 3) / Konst
                Lpi(j) = 10 * Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(p(j))
                SumaLpi(i) = SumaLpi(i) + 10 ^ (0.1 * Lpi(j))
        Next j
    Lp_stredni(i) = 10 * Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(1 / N * SumaLpi(i)) 
         'Lp_stredni(i) WORK WELL
    Lw(i) = 10 * Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(1 / N * SumaLpi(i)) 
         'Lw(i) 'DOESN´T WORKING
    Cells(4, 3 + i) = Lp_stredni(i)
    Next i
```

Comment: your question doesn't match with your code: the former speaks about different constans while your code have comments outlining the malfunctioning for the same value of `Konst` which is not being updated by the code itself. As your code stands nothing would point to a possible issue: if `Lp_stredni(i)` value is set without any error so should `Lw(i)`, too. BTW why are not you simply setting `Lw(i) = Lp_stredni(i)`?

Comment: Konst is still 4*10(-10) for all numbers..

I need to use different formula for Lw(i) but it wasn´t worked (with similar data as p(j)). I tried to use same formula (for Lp_stredni) which is all right to.. just to find a mistake. 

I am confused why same formula works in one time but for second try it doesn´t work??

Comment: you'd better edit your question and show actual code that's not working

Answer (score 0):

p(j) array will most likely have high values, since you are deviding the contents of your cell by "Konst" (which is 0.0000000004), but in your example you have used an array of "Double" type.
I think you should use an array of "Integer" or "Long"

Comment: p(j) are numbers between (10^(-4) to 10^(-10)), 0.0000000004 is 4*10^(-10)

Comment: I tried defined Lw as Long or as Integer but still " it is not possible to bet Log WorksheetFunction

Comment: If you could also send the excel that you want this function to read the data from, it will help a lot. Once I created my own file, and the array of p(j) got results inside, this code worked fine for me.

Comment: Great, I can send you my data.. Could you give an email, please?

Comment: I finally found a way.. I restart Excel and write formula for Lw exactly as for Lp_stredni, just with different data.. I don´t know what is wrong with Application.WorksheetFunction.. But happy that code is working..